# What is “processing” in French?

Tags: informatique, participe-présent

What would be an equivalent of the participle "processing" to signify action, in the sense that something is in the progress?

The shorter the better for my case. But all answers are welcome.

Comment: What is *something* in your question? A bit more info on the context would help.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt, it is related to web pages. Some dynamic elements will be clicked (like forms, file uploads, etc) and somewhere there will be an indicator stating so, but preferably it should be short, but clear.

Comment: IMHO *Traitement en cours* is the best equivalent in your situation. Unfortunately it's not that short. (Literally: *Currently processing*. Writing only *Traitement* would be quite awkward and reflect a bad translation.)

Comment: +1 to both answerers - thank you. I will refrain from accepting, at least for the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say "En cours".

le procès est en cours

Comment: +1 “En cours” could work but “procès” usually means “trial” and would only rarely be used for “process” (I think you might find a few examples but it sounds incredibly pedantic and old-fashioned, certainly not something you could put in a web application).

Comment: "En cours" on its own doesn't mean anything, and I would really find it weird for a translation of "Processing". *Arrête de me texter!! Je suis **en cours**.*

Comment: @Alexandre in this case ("Je suis en cours") "en cours" is a place (at school in a classroom)

Comment: Yes; this was only to illustrate that stating simply "En cours" didn't make sense.

Comment: I think it really depends on the context and the presentation. I agree with @goto about "je suis en cours", it definitely imply that "I'm in the classroom". When it comes to presentation, for example if we have a table of content with different properties of some tasks, you could have columns for "Titre", "Durée" and "Status". The possible values for Status could be "En attente", "En cours" and "Terminé".

Comment: Yes, it all depends on the context, and I agree "En cours" could work in that situation.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing about the context.

Answer (score 8):

I would translate by *En traitement* or *Traitement en cours*.

> Your request is being processed.
>
> Nous traitons votre requête.

Answer (score 3):

Une traduction pas littérale pourrait être: *Veuillez patienter*.

Comment: Which translates to "Please wait."

Answer (score 3):

> Chargement...
>
> Chargement en cours
>
> Nous traitons votre demande

Comment: Which translate to "Loading...", "Now loading" or "Currently loading" and "We're processing your request".